# jq array filter works locally, but not in a GitHub workflow

Tags: bash, github-actions, jq

I'm using jq to extract an array from a JSON in a GitHub workflow:

```
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Test
      run: echo $(echo '{"value":[{"displayName":"test"}]}' | jq -c '.value.[]')
```

However, it fails with the error

```
Run echo $(echo '{"value":[{"displayName":"test"}]}' | jq -c '.value.[]')
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.value.[]       
jq: 1 compile error
```

If I run the same command with jq locally, it works - why doesn't it work on a GitHub runner?

Comment: what shell do you use locally?

Comment: `echo $(cmd)` is useless and can be replaced with simply `cmd` in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `.value.[]`; support for chained `.[]` was added in jq 1.7 (see the [release notes](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7), under "language changes"), and ubuntu-22.04 Actions runners use jq 1.6.

You can fix it by using `.value[]` instead.