# JQ error when trying to parse JSON string - unexpected '['

Tags: json, linux, jq

When trying to query a JSON str, using the script below, I get an error.

```
db_secret_data=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "$db_secret_name" --output json)
    
echo "$db_secret_data"
 
db_secret_str=$(echo "$db_secret_data" | jq --arg keyvar "${uid_str}-TY" '.SecretString.[$keyvar]' -r)
```

Here is the error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.SecretString.[$keyvar]
```

I've gone over the syntax over and over, and can't see what's wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: You seem to be using a version prior to v1.7 (which is the one that introduced the `.a.[b]` notation in Sep 2023 - in addition to the already and still existing `.a[b]` notation).

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78114596/3266847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot before the key:

```
.SecretString[$keyvar]
            ~~
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: @xil3, Well, it is a bit confusing because `.a | .b` can be collapsed into `.a.b`, but `.a | .[]` collapses into `.a[]`

Comment: @ikegami thank you for that explanation - it is indeed very confusing.